# Python: split string and store tokens with delimeters in list

Tags: python, regex, string, list, split

I want split string and store tokens with delimeters in list. What I mean, I have string like this:

```
s = "hi,my+dear-friend*1"
```

And  I want to get:

```
["hi", ",", "my", "+", "dear", "-", "friend", "*", "1"]
```

Comment: What is your definition of a delimiter? Are there a list of accepted delimiters?

Comment: I have list separators "+-*/,=" and have string with text, and I want get list of tokens. I want do something like  class StringTokenizer in Java.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it using regular expression:

```
import re

s = "hi,my+dear-friend*1"
re.findall(r"\w+|\W",s)
```

Output:

```
['hi', ',', 'my', '+', 'dear', '-', 'friend', '*', '1']
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to use capture group with regex.

```
>>> import re
>>> s = "hi,my+dear-friend*1"
>>> re.split(r'(\W)', s)
['hi', ',', 'my', '+', 'dear', '-', 'friend', '*', '1']
```